# Calling method that locks from async method. Is this proper?

Tags: c#, async-await, thread-synchronization

I am creating something that reads from a resource asynchronously, but it should only read every so often and the other times return a cached result. This method is called 10's of thousands of times a minute in an WebAPI ASP.NET Core 2.1 application.

I would like to synchronize the the cached data using a lock of sorts without the overhead of a semaphoreslim object, so I was wondering if this is proper:

```
    private const int LastReadTTL = 5000;
    private static int _lastTickCountRead;
    private static Models.MyModel _lastRead;
    private static readonly object _lock = new object();

    private static bool ShouldRead()
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            var currentTickCount = Environment.TickCount;
            if ((_lastRead == null) || (currentTickCount > (_lastTickCountRead + LastReadTTL)) || (currentTickCount < _lastTickCountRead))
            {
                _lastTickCountRead = currentTickCount;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public async Task<Models.MyModel> ReadSomethingAsync()
    {
        if (ShouldRead())
        {
            _lastRead = await SomethingToReadAsync.ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        return _lastRead;
    }
```

If this isn't proper, why? and is the use of SemaphoreSlim more appropriate in this case?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question belong on codereview.stackexchange.com rather than stackoverflow. In case the question doesn't get moved, my answer would be no, generally it's not a good pattern to lock in an async method.

The reason is that async methods are designed to yield control when unable to progress (typically waiting for IO to complete), so the thread can switch to other tasks that are ready to continue. By blocking the thread, it forces the operating system to do a context switch to another thread, later when the lock is ready for the blocked thread, do another context switch back again. Async was designed specifically to reduce the performance penalty of context switching, so blocking an async method is removing the benefit of the feature.

I recommend using any synchronization object that returns a task you can await on, whether that's semaphoreslim, something from the AsyncEx nuget package, or anything else. Hopefully anyone who created these know more about async in .NET than you or me, so should work better than anything we implement ourselves. There's a good chance they will use a blocking synchronization object, but do so only to avoid race conditions and quickly fall back to async waits when it didn't successfully get the lock, therefore giving the advantages of async while giving the synchronization guarantees required by concurrent systems.

Having said all that, if your use-case is just to update a value periodically, you should look at [Interlocked.Exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.exchange?view=netframework-4.7.2) which gives you a lock-free way of updating a value or object instance.

Comment: Every time I ask a question without posting code, i get yelled at for not posting code. I think every question on SO is a code review, depends on how granular you want to be. Anyway, thanks for the answer. I will move over to `SemaphoreSlim` to  accomplish what I need.

Comment: my understanding is that SO is supposed to be about very specific questions like "I'm trying to do X, I expect result Y, but instead I see result Z." I think this question is more broad with answers possibly more subjective, so maybe better suited to the code review or software engineering sites.

Comment: In case the code you posted is somewhat similar to your real code, my first suggestion is that most of the code you have in the lock can be moved out and you only need to lock in the ReadSomething method when it updates the value. That way when the cached value is not expired, no locks are used. It means you need to do the check twice, once before the lock and once again inside the lock to avoid doing the work multiple times, but if the lock was previosly hit often, the performance should be greatly improved.

Comment: Also, since this is about cached data, it tells me that it is probably not critical for the app to use slightly old data. So, instead of locking other threads while the first thread refreshes data, just keep using the existing cached data. use a lock only to avoid multiple threads attempting to update the value at the same time, although you could also do this with Interlocked.Exchange in a lock-free way.

Comment: Finally, the code you posted does a kind of 'lazy loading', so if your website stops getting traffic (at least traffic that hits this code path), you stop updating the value. But if you don't normally get this periods of inactivity, you can just create a new thread that sleeps until the next cache expiration time and then refreshes the data, and your compute threads just read the data without checking if it's expired, that way your hot code path has no synchronization code slowing it down.

Comment: In conclusion, when doing parallel processing, if performance is truly important, try to be creative in how you use shared data. Thinking procedurally like when writing a single threaded app can lead to locks that block your entire app. There are often ways you can change data structures and algorithms so your performance critical code paths can be lock-free and then your code is much more scalable.